# Applying Hensel's lemma to solve $x^2 + 8 \equiv 0\pmod {121}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, hensels-lemma

When solving for $x^2 + 8 \equiv  0 \pmod {121}$, How can we apply Hensel's lemma to solve for its solutions? What I currently understand is that for a prime $p$ and $e \geq 2$, then $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod {p^{e-1}}$ and comes in the form of $x_e = x_{e-1} - kp^{e-1}$.

Comment: Here is an alternative method: This is solvable be subtracting 8 on both sides to get $x^2\equiv -8\equiv 113\pmod{11^2}$. This system can be solvable using theorem 2.2 here: https://www.uvm.edu/~cvincen1/files/teaching/spring2017-math255/quadraticequation.pdf to get 83 and 38 as the two solutions.

Comment: $x_1\equiv\pm5\pmod{11}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $f(x)=x^2+8\equiv0\bmod11$, one solution of which is $x_0\equiv5\bmod11$. Hensel's lemma to get the solution modulo the next prime power is essentially *Newton's method*:
$$\begin{align}
x_1&\equiv x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}\bmod p^2\\
&\equiv 5-\frac{33}{10}\bmod11^2\\
&\equiv 5+33\cdot12\bmod11^2\\
&\equiv 38\bmod11^2
\end{align}$$
So the two solutions to the modulo-$11^2$ equation are $x\equiv\pm38\bmod11^2$.

Comment: How did you get $x_0 \equiv 5 mod 11$? Sorry I am a bit lost on that part

Comment: @gusf Just try all $11$ values to see if the equation holds $\bmod11$.

Comment: @gusf  Finding square roots modulo a prime is not easy.  As Parcly says, brute force is best for small primes.  For larger primes there is the Tonelli–Shanks algorithm:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli–Shanks_algorithm but it's quite a bit of work.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).